# Using numpy.argmax() on multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, indexing, numpy, closest

I have a 4 dimensional array, i.e., `data.shape = (20,30,33,288)`. I am finding the index of the closest array to n using

```
index = abs(data - n).argmin(axis = 1), so
index.shape = (20,33,288) with the indices varying.
```

I would like to use `data[index] = "values"` with `values.shape = (20,33,288)`, but `data[index]` returns the error *"index (8) out of range (0<=index<1) in dimension 0"* or this operation takes a relatively long time to compute and returns a matrix with a shape that doesn't seem to make sense.

How do I return a array of correct values? i.e.,

```
data[index] = "values" with values.shape = (20,33,288)
```

This seems like a simple problem, is there a simple answer?

I would eventually like to find `index2 = abs(data - n2).argmin(axis = 1)`, so I can perform an operation, say sum data at index to data at index2 without looping through the variables. Is this possible?

I am using python2.7 and numpy version 1.5.1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to access the maximum values indexed by `index` using `numpy.indices()`:

```
x, z, t = numpy.indices(index.shape)
data[x, index, z, t]
```

Comment: Is there also an answer when one doesn't know the ndim?

Comment: @AndreasMueller: Yes, use `tup[:axis] + (index,) + tup[axis:]` as index for `data`, where `tup` is the tuple returned by `numpy.indices()`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, this should work:

```
numpy.put(data, index, values)
```

I learned something new today, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't have "values," so I do not think I can use numpy.put. I believe Sven's answer will work.