# Get indices of numpy.argmax elements over an axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, argmax

I have N-dimensional matrix which contains the values for a function with N parameters. Each parameter has a discrete number of values. I need to maximize the function over all parameters but one, resulting in a one-dimensional vector of size equal to the number of values of the non-maximized parameter. I also need to save which values are taken by the other parameters.

To do so I wanted to iteratively apply `numpy.max` over different axes to reduce the dimensionality of the matrix to find what I need. The final vector will then depend on just the parameter I left out.

I'm however having trouble finding the original indices of the final elements (which contain the information about the values taken by the other parameters). I though about using `numpy.argmax` in the same way as `numpy.max` but I can't obtain back the original indices.

An example of what I'm trying is:

```
x = [[[1,2],[0,1]],[[3,4],[6,7]]]
args = np.argmax(x, 0)
```

This returns

```
[[1 1]
 [1 1]]
```

Which means that argmax is selecting the elements (2,1,4,7) within the original matrix. But how to get their indices? I tried `unravel_index`, using the `args` directly as an index for matrix `x`, a bunch of functions from numpy to index with no success.

Using `numpy.where` is not a solution since the input matrix may have equal values inside, so I would not be able to discern from different original values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`x.argmax(0)` gives the indexes along the 1st axis for the maximum values.  Use `np.indices` to generate the indices for the other axis.

```
x = np.array([[[1,2],[0,1]],[[3,4],[6,7]]])
x.argmax(0)
    array([[1, 1],
           [1, 1]])
a1, a2 = np.indices((2,2))
(x.argmax(0),a1,a2)
    (array([[1, 1],
            [1, 1]]),
     array([[0, 0],
            [1, 1]]),
     array([[0, 1],
            [0, 1]]))


x[x.argmax(0),a1,a2]
    array([[3, 4],
           [6, 7]])

x[a1,x.argmax(1),a2] 
    array([[1, 2],
           [6, 7]])

x[a1,a2,x.argmax(2)] 
    array([[2, 1],
           [4, 7]])
```

If `x` has other dimensions, generate `a1`, and `a2` appropriately.

The official documentation does not say much about how to use `argmax`, but earlier SO threads have discussed it.  I got this general idea from [Using numpy.argmax() on multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798364/using-numpy-argmax-on-multidimensional-arrays)